# RecyclerView.Adapter notifyItemChanged() and click on view not working properly

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

What I'm trying to do is to display a list of cardViews with info in it, and one of the infos is a tablelayout populated with data added by user, so he can edit or delete a tableRow. The problem is that when an object is edit/deleted and notifyitemChanged(position), notifyDataSetChanged(position), notifyItemRemoved(position) methods are called, they duplicate the tableLayout view inside the cardView, giving it a creepy look, like this:

[Tablelayout populated and duplicated after calling notify methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa697.jpg)

```
 private void removeRow(int position, int i) {

    listX.get(position).getListY().remove(i);

    if(listX.get(position).getListY().size()==0){

        listX.remove(position);
        this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.notifyItemChanged(position);

}
```

*removeRow() is called everytime removeIcon is clicked*

```
    private void editRow(ObjectX objectX, int position, int index) {


    Log.i("position : index",position+" : "+index);
    listX.get(position).getListY().get(index).setAttributeX(objectX.getAttributeX());



    this.notifyItemChanged(position);


  }
```

- editRow() is called everytime editIcon is clicked*

OnBindViewHolder()->

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


    HolderExample holder = (HolderExample) viewHolder;


    ObjectX objectX = this.listX.get(position);

    holder.bind(objectX,listener);



    for (TableRow tableRow:getRowsFromFata(objectX)) {

        holder.tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }

}
```

- getRowsFromData(ObjectX objectX)->

  ```
  private List<TableRow> getRowsFromFata(ObjectX objectX){

  List<TableRow> tableRows = new ArrayList<>();

  //... setting layoutParams


  TableRow heading = new TableRow(context);
  //Header
  // ... creating and adding 4 textViews to "heading row" with addView(textView) method    

  tableRows.add(heading);


  //Content
  for(ExampleData exampleData:objextX.getListY()){

     //creating and setting values of 4 textViews with each attribute of ExampleData
  //getListY holds List<ExampleData> listY = ArrayList<>(); 

      ImageView editIcon = new ImageView(context);
      editIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_edit_black);



      editIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

      //opens an AlertDialog and when POSITIVE_BUTTON is clicked calls editRow() method
                  openAddTaskAlertDialog(objectX,listX.indexOf(objectX),objectX.getListY().indexOf(exampleData));

          }
      });

      ImageView removeIcon = new ImageView(context);
      removeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_forever);



      removeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

           removeTaskCompleted(listX.indexOf(objectX),objectX.getListY().indexOf(exampleData));

          }
      });

      TableRow contentRow = new TableRow(context);
      //... adding textViews and ImageViews to contentRow  

      tableRows.add(contentRow);


  }


  return tableRows;

  }
  ```

Comment: You should also post onBindViewHolder method's implementation.

Comment: @KlingKlang Ok, I'll do that.